# How enable digest or basic auth in IIS Express and set a user/password?

Tags: iis, iis-8, basic-authentication, digest, iis-manager

I'm on Windows 2012 R2 and have IIS Express on it. How enable digest or basic auth in IIS Express and where set the username/password?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Enable digest or basic auth in Web.config file

then run

```
iisexpress /config:c:\myconfig\web.config
```

Reference: [IIS Express FAQ](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-faq)
stated

> Q: Does IIS Express use the same configuration system as IIS? A: Yes

Answer (score 0):

For IIS Express only: Settings can be found in
<Project_Location>.vs<Project_Name>\config**applicationhost.config**

[image: Setting Location]

where
<Project_Location> is Project Location
&
<Project_Name> is your Project Name

But before that it's better to enable settings in

[image: Windows Features]

via powershell 7 the command to open Windows Features is **optionalfeatures**